# Past tense of "bulls**t"?

Tags: past-tense

I have heard many things that could be valid ways to express the past tense of the word "bullshit" and other words derived from "shit".

Some examples:

"I bullshit my homework"

"I bullshitted my homework"

"The dog shat on the rug"

Im just curious as to what the accepted past tense of these words is?

Comment: The verb *bullshit* (to deceive) is grammatically different to the verb *shit* (to defecate).  I agree with the full set of conjugations [here](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/bullshit.html).  I particular like the cheery first-person pleural imperative “Let’s bullshit!”.

Comment: @smatterer even the single *t* in *bullshited*? That just looks wrong, like a conjugation of *bullshite*.

Comment: @Chris H, True. I didn't notice the single *t* I guess that spelling is just a load of ... well ...  y'know.

Comment: The last line about the plural makes this question quite confusing.  Bullshit is uncountable, I think, so there's no plural.

Comment: I think most US English speakers would be surprised to learn that "bullshit" is ever considered to be a verb.

Comment: “Bullshatted”????

Answer (score 3):

**bullshitted**.

[bullshitted](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/bullshit) is the past tense and past participle of the word bullshit. although you can use `bullshat` as a past tense but `bullshitted` just rolls out the tongue better (especially when some bullshitting is involved).

As for the past tense of *shit*, there is *shat* or *shitted*, but the commonly used form is *shat*. It is, [according to Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/shat/),

> the widely accepted past-tense inflection of *shit*. It was formed by analogy with the verb *sit*, which becomes *sat* in the past tense. It was originally a humorous and slightly sanitized version of the curse word, but it has become the standard form.

Comment: fixed original question

Comment: By "shatted", I assume you mean "shitted"?  The OED has past tense options of "shit", "shitted" and "shat", but no "shatted".  Interestingly, the older form of the verb is "shite" in its infinitive and present tense forms, with "shit" being originally the past tense.  ("Shite" of course is still in use in some dialects.)

Comment: yes, i mean "shitted"

Comment: This post plagiarizes the linked Grammarist article. Since you linked the article presumably it's just an accident you didn't indicate the quotation. I wonder why you took the lifted material out of sentence case? -- anyway I will submit an edit to cite the author.